# ドメインを登録したのですがサイトに飛ばずルーターの設定画面に飛びます

Tags: dns

freenomでドメインを登録してそのURLにアクセスしたのですが、なぜか作ったサイトに飛ばず、ルーターの設定画面に飛びます。
なぜこういうことが起こるのか、解決方法があれば教えてください。

補足:
IPアドレスなどはグローバルIPを登録しています。

追記:
プロバイダ:gc119-10-188-228.gctv.ne.jp
契約情報などは確認できませんでした(親が管理しているため)

Comment: これだけだとまだ情報が足りません。ルーターとは自分のネットワークのものですか？またグローバルIPアドレスはどのように確認しましたか？

Comment: ルーターは自分の家のものです
グローバルIPは確認くん(https://www.ugtop.com/spill.shtml )というものをつかって確認しました

Comment: 自宅ですか、であればプロバイダとサーバ公開にあたり、利用しているプランや契約状況を追記してください。

Comment: 追記しました。
契約情報などは親が管理しているため確認できませんでした

Comment: 可能であれば LAN の外から (例えばスマホから) アクセスして、意図した通りドメインが開けるかを確認するなどして、問題部分の切り分けを行うと良いかもしれません。

Comment: ドメイン名とIPアドレスが正しくつながっているか、確認するにはNSLOOKUPというコマンドが便利です。コマンドプロンプトからNSLOOKUPを起動し、ドメイン名を入力してみてください。NSLOOKUPの詳しい使い方は、検索してみてください。

Comment: 池田茂樹さん
わかりましたNSLOOKUPためしてみます

Answer (score 1, accepted):

おそらくご自宅にサーバを立ててWebページを公開したいという気持ちで進めているのかと思います。
しかしながら、自宅でサーバを立てるためにはいくつか壁があり、ネットワークの知識とお金が必要です。

まず自宅にネットワークを引く場合は一般的には自宅やマンション向けのネットワークを提供しているプロバイダに固定のグローバルIPを払い出しおよびサーバ設置の許可をを受ける必要があります。
そのためにはプロバイダと契約の確認が必要なのです。
ご自身で契約していないことおよび地方のケーブルテレビ等はあまりあまりそういったプランを提供していないことが多いので、今の質問者様の環境では難しいのではないかと推測します。
勝手にサーバを立てると契約違反になってしまう可能性もありますので、ご注意ください。
まずは親御さんに確認してプロバイダの契約を確認してみてください。

もし契約しているプロバイダがサーバを立てられる場合は
ルーター等の設備の設定が正しくない可能性があります。
一般的に市販のルーターだけですとNATの設定だったりポートフォワーディングだったりができないこともあるので、まずはご自身で調べてみるほうが良いと思います。

ルータが設定してもサーバの設定もきちんと確認しないといけません。
Webサーバが正しく設定されているか？サーバのネットワークの設定がどうなっているのか？
FireWall等のセキュリティの設定が正しくされているのか？
この辺りの知識が必要です。

またネットワークに公開すると攻撃されます。
そのためネットワークセキュリティの知識も必要です。
ルータからサーバに関してそれ相応のセキュリティを維持しておかないと重大な事故になる可能性もあります。

学習のためにご自宅でネットワークを引くのは知識とお金が必要なのでAWS、heroku、GCP等のPaasの無料枠を利用してサーバを立てたり、学生であるならば教育向けに無料のサービスがいくつかあるのでそれを利用してみるのも手です。

単純に無料でサーバを公開したいということであれば静的なサイト限定ですが[GitHub Pages](https://docs.github.com/ja/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages)を利用もよいでしょう。

この辺りを改めて一通り検索したもらってご自身にあったものを試してみるとよいでしょう。

Comment: なるほど....
契約によってサーバーが建てられるか変わってくるんですね....知りませんでした..
一度親に契約の変更ができるか等の相談をしてみます
回答ありがとうございました

Answer (score 0):

ドメイン登録の次はDNSサーバーの設定になります。
既にDNSサーバーが設定済みであれば、今ある他の回答が的確です。

> 「登録」という言葉があり、「DNSサーバー」や「設定」という単語が登場していないのが気になりました。

DNSサーバーが設定済みの状況であれば、、

> 以下のWiresharkを使う前に、先ずはnslookupですね。（※コメントから）

Wiresharkなどクライアントとサーバーのやり取りを追えば、原因となっているサーバーのレスポンスが分かると思います。それについて可能な範囲で調べて整理し、また質問するなど。

> Wiresharkで追うのは面倒な作業ですが、丁寧に追えば原因箇所は特定できるので手段として使えることは損ではありません。DNSサーバーの設定ができるのであれば、どうにか基準は満たしていると思います。